# How to put square brackets inside a table?

Tags: tables, brackets

Assuming I have a table like this,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\newcommand{\smbullet}{{\scriptscriptstyle\bullet}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c }\hline
$ H$ & VB-3 & VB-2 & VB-1&CB+1&CB+2&\\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & a &b & c \\
1 & 2 & 3 & d &e & f \\
1 & 2 & 3 & g &h & i \\
a & b & c & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
d & e & f & 1 &2 & 3 \\
g & h & i & 1 &2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

How do I put a brackets to the upper right 3x3 matrix and lower left 3x3 and instead of inputs from a to i, just insert a bracket with H inside.

Comment: Take a look at `nicematrix` and its sub block feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c}[first-row]
\hline
$ H$ & VB-3 & VB-2 & VB-1&CB+1&CB+2\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & \Block{3-3}{H} & &  \\
1 & 2 & 3 &  & &  \\
1 & 2 & 3 &  & &  \\
\Block{3-3}{H}
 &  &  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 &  &  & 1 &2 & 3 \\
 &  &  & 1 &2 & 3 \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-4}{3-6}][extra-height=-3pt,xshift=-2mm]
  \SubMatrix[{4-1}{6-3}][extra-height=-3pt]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 5):

You can insert the left/right brace manually, knowing the height of the rows you're working with. In your case, with the matrices spanning 3 rows, place the left/right braces on the middle row, `\smash`ed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
  \toprule
  $H$ & $VB - 3$ & $VB - 2$ & $VB - 1$ & $CB + 1$ & $CB + 2$ \\
  \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 & a & b & c \\
  \llap{\smash{$\left[\vphantom{\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}}\right.$}}1 & 2 & 
    3\rlap{\smash{$\left.\vphantom{\begin{array}{c} 3 \\ 3 \\ 3 \end{array}}\right]$}} & d & e & f \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & g & h & i \\
  a & b & c & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  d & e & f & \llap{\smash{$\left[\vphantom{\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}}\right.$}}1 & 2 & 
    3\rlap{\smash{$\left.\vphantom{\begin{array}{c} 3 \\ 3 \\ 3 \end{array}}\right]$}} \\
  g & h & i & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```